# Spark Streaming Write Ahead Logs with Custom Receiver

Tags: java, apache-spark, streaming, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming application using a Custom Receiver and I want it to be fully fault-tolerant. To do so, I have enabled Write Ahead Logs (WAL) in the configuration file when running spark-submit and have checkpointing set up (using getOrCreate).

From a tutorial I saw online, it says that to make sure WAL is recovering buffered data properly with custom receiver, I need to make sure that the receiver is reliable and data is acknowledged after it is saved to WAL directory. The reference on Spark website also talks about acknowledging data from source:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/streaming-custom-receivers.html

However, there is no example code of how to set up the order for:

1. First save data to WAL (by calling store())
2. Acknowledge the data (??)

Any idea how I can do it?
Currently, in my Spark UI, I see that the application resumes with multiple batches having "0 events".